# Cython No such file or directory: '.pyd' error on Windows

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to build the [Hello World example](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) from Cython tutorial.
I have written both hello.pyx and setup.py files:

```
# hello.pyx
def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

---

```
# setup.py
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(
  name='Hello world app',
  ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
)
```

When I run

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the following error:

```
copying build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\cython_test\hello.pyd -> cython_test
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython_test\\hello.pyd'
```

Build process works fine and I get a working `hello.pyd` file, but for some reason setup.py cannot copy the `.pyd` back into the working directory. How can I fix that?

*hello.pyx and setup.py files are also available at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/lgyanf/cython-no-such-file/src)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved this issue. It appeared that `python setup.py` command should be executed outside the project directory. The following code works fine.

```
cd ..
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

UPDATE: a better way to solve the issue is to specify the `package_dir` option to `setup` function:

```
setup(
    name='Hello world app',
    package_dir={'cython_test': ''},
    ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
)
```

Answer (score 11):

Hopefully this will be useful to others experiencing this error. After some digging, my problem was due the `__init__.py` file in the same directory. [This github issue](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/issues/382) highlights the potential problem. After removing the `__init__.py`, I now get the correct `.pyd` file in the directory.